# Stripe payment status showing "requires_payment_method", why? in swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, stripe-payments

I have integrated stripe in my project

code: here in payButton serviceCall success response I am getting payment intent data so here I am presenting stripe card.. after adding stripe card number exp date and cvv i am getting paymentMethodId with this and payment intentId(transaction id from paybutton success response) i have called save_payment API in `didCreatePaymentMethod` after calling all two APIs in stripe dashboard payment incomplete and status like below.. why? where am i wrong.. please guide me

> status showing "requires_payment_method"

> not getting charges data as well
> {
> "id": "pi_3LWMATIAbhwaLb1OenxVAI",
> "object": "payment_intent",
> "livemode": false,

```
"status": "requires_payment_method",

"amount": 1170,
"amount_received": 0,
"charges": {
    
    "object": "list",
    
    "data": [
    ],


import UIKit
import Stripe
class NewBuyRequestPaymentVC: UIViewController, STPAddCardViewControllerDelegate{

@IBAction func payButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    
    let param: [String: Any] = [
        "description": descriptionTextField.text ?? "No description",
        "amount": amountTextField.text ?? "0.0",
        "enquiry_id": enqrId ?? "",
    ]
    
    APIReqeustManager.sharedInstance.serviceCall(param: param, method: .post, url: CommonUrl.request_payment){ [weak self] (resp) in
        
        self?.makePayment = PaymentNewBuyModel(dictionary: resp.dict as NSDictionary? ?? NSDictionary())
        
        self?.paymentIntentClientSecret = self?.makePayment?.result?.intent?.client_secret
        paymentIntentId = makePayment?.result?.intent?.id
        
        //here i am presenting stripe viewcontoller with card
        let config = STPPaymentConfiguration.shared
        config.requiredBillingAddressFields = .none
        let viewController = STPAddCardViewController(configuration: config, theme: STPTheme.defaultTheme)
        viewController.delegate = self
        let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: viewController)
        self?.present(navigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

func addCardViewControllerDidCancel(_ addCardViewController: STPAddCardViewController) {
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)}

@objc
func addCardViewController(_ addCardViewController: STPAddCardViewController, didCreatePaymentMethod paymentMethod: STPPaymentMethod, completion: @escaping STPErrorBlock) {
    paymentMethodId = paymentMethod.stripeId
    print("payment method id \(paymentMethodId ?? "")")
    savePaymentServiceCall()
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func savePaymentServiceCall(){
    
    print("payment transaction and method id \(String(describing: paymentIntentId)), \(String(describing: paymentMethodId))")
    
    let param = ["term_id" : makePayment?.result?.term_id?.description ?? "",
                 "payment_method" : paymentMethodId ?? "",
                 "intent_id" : paymentIntentId ?? ""
    ] as [String : Any]
    APIReqeustManager.sharedInstance.serviceCall(param: param as [String : Any], method: .post, url: CommonUrl.save_payment) { [weak self] (resp) in
        
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In payment you shouldn't use `STPAddCardViewController`, instead you should use `STPPaymentContext` which opens `STPPaymentOptionsViewController`. `STPAddCardViewController` is for add card for future use. On Stripe side adding credit card during checkout is different procedure than adding credit card for future use.

For more information you can check the Stripe pre-build ui payment [documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/ios/basic).

Comment: Could you please tell me which method should i use to make payment... i  dont need to show to show payment method options view controller.. just i need to add payment method.. please let me know